# Switch toggle return to previous state when I click "No" in the alert prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a switch toggle that allows the system administrator to activate/deactivate the login access of an account.

After the admin click the switch toggle (the switch moving from state 1 to 0), it will prompt via alert box a confirmation (Do you want to activate / deactivate this account? Yes | No), whenever I click "no," I want it to return to its previous state (from 0 to 1).

I manage to successfully do this if the state is "1" [The account is activated], but when it's the other way around, from status 0 to 1, the switch toggle doesn't return back to its previous state and gets stuck to state 1.

It still sends the proper POST command tho (e.g. deactivates the account if it's activated, and vice versa), but the visual display is wrong.

This is my code.

**Javascript for the toggle switch**

```js
var chk;
    $(document).on('change', '.btn-change-status', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      chk = $(this);
      var switch_status = $(this).attr('data-status');
      var account_status = (switch_status == 1) ? 0 : 1;
      var id  = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var confirm_alert = (switch_status == 1) ? confirm("Are you sure you want to deactivate this account?") : confirm("Are you sure you want to activate this account?");
        if (confirm_alert == true) {
         $.ajax({
              url: "/user/update-status",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
                id: id,
                status: account_status
              },
              success: function(data) {
                if (data.success === true) {
                  alert("Account Successfully Updated!");
                  location.reload();
                }
              }

            });
        }
        else {
          if(chk.checked) {
            chk.prop("checked", false);
          }
          else {
            chk.prop("checked", true);
          }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:** added the HTML part of the switch, although it's still in javascript coz I attached it to a dataTable.

**HTML of the dataTable**

```html
 <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
              <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
              Accounts Management</div>
            <div class="card-body">

              <button type="button" id="btn-add-account" class="btn btn-primary">Add Account</button>
              <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
                <table class="table table-bordered dt-responsive" id="table-accounts" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="hidden">ID</th>
                      <th>Username</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Role</th>
                      <th>Date Created</th>
                      <th style="width: 15.5%">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="hidden">ID</th>
                      <th>Username</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Role</th>
                      <th>Date Created</th>
                      <th style="width: 15.5%">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </div>
```

**Javascript of the dataTable**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    getRoles();
    var accounts;
     $('#account-management').addClass('active');

    accounts = $("#table-accounts").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "/users/get-all-users",
          dataSrc: ''
        },
        responsive:true,
        "order": [[ 7, "desc" ]],
        columns: [
        { data: 'id'},
        { data: 'username' },
        { data: 'email'},
        { data: 'role.id'},
        { data: 'created_at'},
        { data: null,
          render: function ( data, type, row ) {
            var html = "";
            if (data.status == 1) {
              html += '<span class="switch switch-sm"> <input type="checkbox" class="switch btn-change-status" id="'+data.id+'" data-id="'+data.id+'" data-status="'+data.status+'" checked> <label for="'+data.id+'"></label></span>';
            } else {
              html += '<span class="switch switch-sm"> <input type="checkbox" class="switch btn-change-status" id="'+data.id+'" data-id="'+data.id+'" data-status="'+data.status+'"> <label for="'+data.id+'"></label></span>';
            }
              html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-edit-account mr-2' data-id='"+data.id+"' data-account='"+data.id+"'>Edit</button>";
              html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-reset-password' data-id='"+data.id+"' data-account='"+data.id+"'><i class='fas fa-key'></i></button>";

            // <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-edit' data-id='"+data.id+"' data-account='"+data.id+"'>Edit</button> 
            // html += "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete' data-id='"+data.id+"' data-account='"+data.id+"'>Remove</button>";

            return html;
          } 
        },
        ],
        columnDefs: [
        { className: "hidden", "targets": [0]},
         { "orderable": false, "targets": 4 }
        ]
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many values that represent the same thing. You only need two values:

1. id: [type: String] id of the checkbox.
2. status: [type: Boolean] By default a checkbox value is `true` if checked and `false` if not checked.

In this case you don't need any `data-*` attributes, but if you still think you do, use `.data()` method instead:

```
$('.status').data('id') // Returns the value of `data-id` on each `input.status`
```

If for some reason you find that you need to use more values for such a trivial task you need to reevaluate your code fundamentally. Details are commented in demo, it uses a live test server to verify what was sent to it.

```js
/* This function extracts the value of each output.member and then assigns a 
   modified version of the value as the id of the checkbox that follows (input.status)
   This is not required to answer the OP's question and is intended just to provide each
   checkbox with a unique id */
$('.member').each(function(index) {
  let user = $(this).val().split('@')
  let id = user[0] + '-' + index;
  $(this).next('.status').attr('id', id);
});

// Any change event occuring on any input.staus (checkbox)...
$('.status').on('change', function(e) {

  // A boolean that reflects the checkbox "check status"
  let checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  
  // A simple confirm...
  let changed = confirm("Are you sure you want to change this account?");
  
  //... if user cancels...
  if (!changed) {
  
    /* ...ternary: [?][if checkbox is checked] - [uncheck it] [:][otherwise] - [check it]
    [return][Terminate function - don't do anything else] */
    return checked ? $(this).prop('checked', false) : $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
  
  /* function continues here if user confirmed by clicking "OK"
     The data will be posted to a live test server.
     A link will appear at the bottom, follow the directions to verify response */
  let ID = this.id;
  let active = checked ? 1 : 0;
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://ptsv2.com/t/status/post",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      id: ID,
      status: active
    },
     success: function() {
       $('.response').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  font: 16px/1 Arial
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.member {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25ch;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.status {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.response {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 99vw
}

.response * {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px auto;
  width: 90%
}
```

```html
<form id='admin-panel'>
  <fieldset class='member-status'>
    <legend>Member Status</legend>
    <label>
    <output class='member'>zer00ne@gmail.com</output>
    Status: <input class='status' type='checkbox' checked>
    </label>
    <label>
    <output class='member'>tech.artificer@gmail.com</output>
    Status: <input class='status' type='checkbox' checked>
    </label>
    <label>
    <output class='member'>joker666@4chan.org</output>
    Status: <input class='status' type='checkbox'>
    </label>
    <label>
    <output class='member'>byte.my@ss.com</output>
    Status: <input class='status' type='checkbox' checked>
    </label>
    <label>
    <output class='member'>bruce@wayne.com</output>
    Status: <input class='status' type='checkbox' checked>
    </label>
    <label>
    <output class='member'>clark.kent@dailyplanet.com</output>
    Status: <input class='status' type='checkbox' checked>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <hr>
  <output class='response'>
    <a href="https://ptsv2.com/t/status/d/latest" target='view'>Click then scroll down to <i style='display:inline'>Parameters</i> inside the iframe below</a>
    <iframe name='view'></iframe>
  </output>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This helped me solve my problem, thank you!

Also, I'll take note of what you said about the use of values, thank you again !! :))

Comment: That's great. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

**Could you please update your post with your HTML, as I am unsure about the situation described in the question.** I had an idea as to why the code doesn't work, but need to see the HTML to investigate further. **In hindsight, I realise that my solution probably does not address the problem.**

If the element with the class `btn-change-status` is a `<button>` tag in HTML, then jQuery's `.on("change", handler)` will not work *(where `handler` is your function)*. According to the jQuery documentation:

> The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.

Instead, I would recommend using one of the following:

- `.on("click", handler)`
- `.on("mouseup", handler)`
- `.on("mousedown", handler)`

See which one works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using class selector '.btn-change-status'

```
chk = $(this);
```

chk is now a collection with 1 element. To check whether it is checked use

```
chk.prop('checked')
```

or

```
chk[0].checked
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the ajax and trying to toggle your input at the wrong event. You have to handle those events on the **yes** button of the popup not in the **change** event.

The code should clear it out.

```
 $(document).on('change', '.btn-change-status', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var chk = $(this);
  var switch_status = $(this).attr('data-status');
  var account_status = (switch_status == 1) ? 0 : 1;
  var id  = $(this).attr('data-id');
  popUpConfirmation(id, status);
});

function popUpConfirmation(id,status) {
   //popup opens here is visible 
   $("#ok-button").data("id", id);
    $("#ok-button").data("status", status);
}

$("#ok-button").on('click', function() {
  var id  = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var status = $(this).attr('data-status');

  var checkbox = $("input[data-id='"+id+"']");
  if(checkbox.prop('checked')) {
     checkbox.prop('checked',false);
  } else {
     checkbox.prop('checked',true);
  }

   $.ajax({
          url: "/user/update-status",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
            id: id,
            status: account_status
          },
          success: function(data) {
            if (data.success === true) {
              alert("Account Successfully Updated!");
              location.reload();
            }
          }

        });

});

$("#cancel-button").on('click', function() {
  //close or hide the popup
});
```

For the popup create a view. This can be anything a div or a button, or you can use modal-view popups. the main key thing is the triggering buttons.

```
<div class="popup">
  <input type="button" id="ok-button"></input>
   <input type="button" id="cancel-button"></input>
</div>
```

This should fix your view issue without changing your code much. You can shorten the code using ternary operator. But I want to keep it simple for others to be able to understand too.

Fell free to ask if you have any queries.

I hope this helps...Happy coding.